# Fix table resize with jquery animation

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Using ASP.NET, I have a GridView to display some data.  There is an option on the screen to hide\show additional data depending on a checkbox.  If the checkbox is clicked, I hide\show an additional column of data in my GridView.

My issue is this.  My UI looks very slick because of jquery fades and what not, but after the column of data is hidden\shown, the table automatically resizes and "jumps" when it's resized to it's new width.  Because this happens "automatically", I'm unsure if there is some event I can key off of to add a fade to, or perhaps there's a way for me to manually trigger the table resize, appending my animation to that?

In short, how can I control\add animation to a table resize on my page?  Thanks!

Comment: I hope I understand your issue. Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emgee/vf99m/) and see if it is the behaviour you are looking for (or at least something in the general direction)?

Comment: Perfect, thanks!!!  Please post as a separate answer so I can reward you accordingly.  THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ewitkows

Use jQuery's `.toggle()` to animate the hide/show so it doesn't jump.

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emgee/vf99m/) and see if it is the behaviour you are looking for (or at least something in the general direction)?

Glad I could help!

Cheers!